# Binding cert to port command including unwanted parameters

Tags: batch-file, command, certificate

I'm using the following command in a batch file:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8502 certhash=‎A91C764627942494ECC31415F52281D478EFF674 appid={5f8e92c2-0af7-4a83-b6fb-491662e87456}
```

When the command is read in an extra set of characters are prepended onto the certhash giving the following command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8502 certhash=ÔÇÄ‎A91C764627942494ECC31415F52281D478EFF674 appid={5f8e92c2-0af7-4a83-b6fb-491662e87456}
```

This is causing the command to fail. What could be causing this and is there a workaround to it?

I also noticed copying and pasting the command straight into a cmd will prepend ? symbols instad of what is seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally got it right after asking the question. 
It was a hidden character that was being copied over from the certificate thumbprint. When copying the thumbprint I just didn't copy the first and last empty space